# what will the original object become after merge on it

Tags: hibernate, grails

I have a question about the Merge() method  in Grails, i read the doc and i understood that this method return a persistent object, but i don't find any explanations about what the original oject(detached) has became.

I would like take an example :

```
request_1 : usr=User.get(id); Hibernate.initialize(usr.rules) ; session.currentUser = usr
request_2 : session.currentUser.merge() // i've ignored the returned attached object
request_3 : log.info session.currentUser.rules.collect{it.authority} // Lazy loading exception
```

just like the code shown, i force the initialiazation of "rules" collection of "usr" instance, and then i save it in the httpSession.
in the second request, "session.usr" is became detached, i do a merge() on it and i ignored the returned attached object, because i would examine the state of the original detached object in the httpsession.
in the third request, i try to access to "rules" collection and i get a "lazy loading exception", but in the first request, the "rules" collection has been loaded...

Answer (score 1):

The object returned by `merge()` is not the same as the instance you have in the session, but instead a combination of a new instance and the state from the detached object that you saved in the HTTP session. You need to make sure that the associations are initialised following the merge. Frankly, it can be more efficient to perform a eager finder and perform a manual merge.

Comment: Thank you rocher, but i still don't understand why the collection that i've forced loaded are not in memory anymore after the merge()? the "rules" collection is loaded by using Hibernate.initialize(usr.rules), and then i store "usr" instance in httpsession. In the next request, "session.usr" become detached, if i merge it back into hibernate session, and then i try to access to "rules" collection of the original detached object "session.usr", i get a "lazy loading exception", but i've initialized this collection before.